# Developing App using PCL and IoC with annotations

Tags: c#, annotations, portable-class-library

I'm writing an app using PCL libs and IoC patterns to facilitate cross platform development on iOS, Android, etc. My repository implements the IRepository patten and I have a concrete implementation that uses the SQLite.Net ORM. In order to get the full benefit of SQLite.Net I need to decorate my models with annotations e.g.

```
public class Stock
{
   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

At some stage I might decide to develop another concrete implementation e.g. Repository X.

My question is:

Having annotations like this introduces a dependency on SQLite for my model/entity, which is essentially just a POCO. So, how do I have the annotations, without the dependency ? For example, if I used Repository X in future, and dropped SQLite, I'd need to drop the annotations ?

One way I was thinking of doing it was to define an abstract class and my derived class has the annotations on it. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

you can see if Sqlite has any type of XML Mapping association of class/attributes (Like LINQ.Data does)

or any type of usage of metadata. Like MVC does on models:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TestMetadata))]
class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class TestMetadata
{
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```